# Should 「ソウル」 be pronounced as "so u ru" or "so: ru"?

Tags: pronunciation, long-vowels

According to the ipadic attached to [Mecab](https://code.google.com/p/mecab/), it's "so u ru".

According to the bccwj dict attached to [Julius](http://julius.sourceforge.jp/), it's "so: ru".
Which one is correct? Or are they both OK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ソウル is the pronunciation given in the NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典, but both pronunciations are in use; some speakers pronounce it ソール instead.

From *The Sounds of Japanese* (Vance 2008), pages 67-68:

> Katakana spellings of recent borrowings and foreign proper names with ウ (*u*) instead of ー (the length mark) do represent /ou/, but these are rare; *Souru* ソウル 'Seoul' in Table 3-8 is one of very few examples (and many speakers do have the pronunciation /soHru/ rather than /souru/).<sup>37</sup>

From footnote 37:

> <sup>37</sup>The entry in Kindaichi and Akinaga 2001 gives ソウル (implying /ou/) first but also gives ソール (implying /oH/).  NHK 1998:1015 gives only ソウル in its list of foreign place names.

Note: the /H/ symbol in phonemic transcriptions indicates a long vowel.

Answer (score 2):

The pronunciation closest to Korean is So-ul, with an open o, u sound as in 'tour' and unreleased final consonant, to match 서울. So the closest in Japanese would be ソ・ウル, losing the close/open o distinction, the u/e distinction and unreleased 'l' (the l/r is the same in Korean and Japanese though).

Answer (score 0):

ソウル (Seoul) is pronounced Souru. There's a long O sound in the "So" which is written in English as either Souru or Sōru.