# Difficult to understand katakana of the word "though"

Tags: katakana, english-to-japanese, phonology, gemination

So, I'm not proficient in Japanese but, as a programmer, I decided to create a program to generate katakana equivalents of english words automatically.

I have had some success, but with some ambiguities.
For example, the phonetics for "though" being:

```
(American): /ðo/
(British): /ðəʊ/
```

My program generates: `ゾー`

A friend of mine told me that `ゾゥ`, also corresponds to "though", but she couldn't explain me why.

I guess what I want to know is what is the reasoning behind deciding the conversion of `though` to either have `ー` or `ゥ`?

> I read in a paper study, saying that most katakana words are derived from British english.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20932/7810

Comment: How did you write this program yet don't understand what it outputs?

Comment: I made a question, I wish you could understand what's being asked instead of making a baseless comment. This is not a programming channel, I asked according to the purpose of this channel.

Comment: It's not possible to write a program which outputs something and you don't know why it outputs that.

Comment: The question is not about what my program outputs. If you need some clarification ask the right questions instead of making your wrong premises.

Comment: I am not sure that ゾー, pronounced zoo, is the best translitteration, but ゾゥ, pronounced "zu", is for sure not close... They do not have the ð sound in Japanese, it is usually changed to "z" sound, and the "o"-sound in though is also not present in Japanese.

Comment: Here it is translitterated as ゾォゥ (Zou), which I guess makes sense, I am not confident enough to put this as an answer though, and I have never encountered a usage of two small kana letters together, but I guess this is one way of writing the diphtong in though.
https://en.hatsuon.info/word/though

Comment: dryleaf, @Ben's question is not baseless.  It is very confusing to me as well that you've written a program but don't understand the output.  You could follow your own advice about clarifying and asking the right questions, by editing your question to make it more clear what you're asking about.  Right now, your post reads to me that you don't understand your own conversion algorithm.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I'm a born-and-raised speaker of American English, and the IPA above for "though" doesn't look right at all -- English in general, including American English, has few straight vowels, outside of some regional accents like Minnesotan.  My subjective understanding matches what I see in [the Wiktionary entry here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/though), where AmE pronunciation is given as //ðoʊ// instead, with an explicitly marked diphthong.

Comment: I believe you're taking the word "conversion" too literally here. The way I understood his question is that due to his friend offering an alternative, he now wants to know where the exact difference lies and why you'd opt for either one. Can't really see anything in his post asking about algorithms tbh.

Comment: @Boolicious, it's a confusingly written post.  The incorrect IPA for AmE, the strange mention of 外来語 from British English that's presented as a quote from someone else, the lack of general context (what's the use case? who will use the output? how will they use it? does it matter if this reflects various English regionalisms? etc.), the slightly off English in the writing itself, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a native English speaker, but as Eiríkr Útlendi pointed out in the comment section, I feel there is a /ʊ/ sound even in American English (as long as the word is pronounced slowly and clearly). This can be confirmed by several sources on the net.

- Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/though#Pronunciation
- Forvo: https://forvo.com/word/though/

However, Japanese speakers are generally bad at English [diphthongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong), and they are often replaced by long vowels when katakanized, anyway. For example "no" (/noʊ/) is normally written as ノー rather than ノゥ, and "page" (/peɪdʒ/) is ページ rather than ペィジ.

So, it ultimately depends on your purpose. ゾゥ is more "faithful" in a sense and preferred in dictionaries (e.g., see [ALC's entry](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=though&ref=sa)), but ゾー is perfectly acceptable in many other cases.

By the way, what is your program's output for "note"? If it's ノート, then ゾー may be more consistent. But if your program outputs ノゥト, then you may want it to output ゾゥ for "though", too.

Comment: For `note` outputs `ノート`, `although` outputs `オールゾー`, `those` outputs `ゾーズ`

Comment: @dryleaf Then ゾー seems perfectly reasonable to me!

Comment: dryleaf's software looks very similar to the output of this online converter: [note](https://www.sljfaq.org/cgi/e2k.cgi?word=note), [although](https://www.sljfaq.org/cgi/e2k.cgi?word=although), [those](https://www.sljfaq.org/cgi/e2k.cgi?word=those).